# How can I rewrite the sentence for technical writing style

Tags: technical-writing, academic-writing

I want to rewrite my sentence in technical writing style. Could you help me rewrite my sentence? Thank you in advance

> The proposed methods has 4 variables need to update in a optimization process, comparison with 2 variables in the method A, 3 variables in method B. Thus, it requires more time consuming, but it provides more accuracy.

The sentence means the proposed method has 4 variables which need to updates in a optimization process. More variables tends to more accuracy, but it is less effective in computational time.

Comment: Welcome to Writers.  Rephrasing requests are off-topic here (see the links in the on-hold notice), but it's also not clear what you mean by "technical writing style".  There's not just one style; it varies by type of writing and by audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably write it something like this:

> The proposed method uses 4 variables, 2 more than method A and one more than method B. This gives a more accurate result, but it requires more computational time.

Comment: How about if I list some methods in existing methods as: 2 variables of method A, 1 variables of method A and 3 variables of method C. Can I use "instead of". And third variables is not cause to complexity. Number of variable is reason why more computational time

Comment: Now I'm confused. Can you edit the question to include all relevant information because your comment adds information you didn't include originally?

Comment: I updated it. I used 4 variable to in my text, instead of 3 in previous text